# Does this make sense? "Shows you follow are in your library"

Tags: meaning

I saw this on an application and it sounded wrong to me. How can it be changed to make more sense?

> Shows you follow are in your library.

Comment: What is it supposed to mean?

Comment: I suspect "There are shows. You follow some. The shows you follow are in your library."

Comment: Seems fine to me. I assume the context where it's used will make the reference to "shows" clear.

Comment: You could add "The" before "shows" to avoid parsing it as a verb.

Comment: *The shows that you follow are added to your library.*

Comment: @TinfoilHat Unless they don't guarantee to include _all_ the shows that you follow in your lbrary.

Comment: @BoldBen If it's similar to many video/podcast applications I've used, the "library" is where you find your personal collections of things, such as the shows you follow.

Comment: I suspect it means that **links to** some shows can be found in your mailbox (whatever that is, in context).

Answer (score 1):

@[Tinfoil Hat](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/206976/tinfoil-hat) wrote in a [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/561116/does-this-sound-right-to-you#comment1386387_561116):

> **The** shows **that** you follow are added to your library.

This was probably the intended meaning of the 'sentence': If you follow a certain show, it will be added to your library.

---

[Will delete if asked to by the original commenter]